# Azure blob not deletable via CDN

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have created an Azure Akamai CDN with an endpoint connected to a storage account (block blob only). I generated a SAS Token with full permissions and it is used to access to a specific container using the CDN endpoint. The SAS Token gives the delete permission and the blobs are deletable throught storage account address (mystorage.blob.core.windows.net) but not deletable throught CDN endpoint (my-cdn.azureedge.net).

Is there a way to delete a blob via CDN endpoint?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I found that is a Storage Explorer (or AzCopy) issue. It works by REST API and SDK.